# FME-Flow (Server) - Has a jobs queue while no running job

Tags: fme-flow

Our FME Server has a queue of jobs, but no job running.
I have found possible reasons of that
https://community.safe.com/s/article/fme-server-jobs-are-not-processing-and-engines-are

I checked engine, it is available, but it shows "Current job" 35251 - the one which was stuck and cancelled. Looks like it is still stuck on it.

[image]

I already restarted FME Engine and FMEServerAppServer services. But it didn't helped.

[image]

I am also getting this:

[image]

Found this thread, but don't understand what the solution is:
https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D54Q000080hMf9SAE/fme-server-aborted-job-keeps-running-on-engine

Can you help, please?